# WEKA how to translate a KnowledgeFlow file in code for SimpleCli?

Tags: weka

I developed a good system for my task using WEKA KnowldgeFlow saving a .kf file and now I'd like to translate it to use into the SimpleCli command line.
I don't want to run a kf file from SimpleCli but to obtain a code.
Does exist a method or plugin to make it automatically ?

Thanks

I searched a plugin without results.

Comment: What is the reason behind switching from KnowledgeFlow to SimpleCLI?

Comment: I need to reproduce the same results and to visualize the code and the variables in the SimpleCli or Eclipse IDE to make some changes to adapt it to my task and to verify that the process is feasible. In few words I need a work environement similar to Matlab or Phyton.

Comment: You can write Java code (using the Weka API) using the [jshell-scripting](https://github.com/fracpete/jshell-scripting-weka-package) Weka package, if you want to avoid compilation. For using the Weka API, have a look at the [Weka wiki](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/using_the_api/) on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a plugin. Since you can do more complicated things with the KnowledgeFlow than with the SimpleCLI, i.e., you may not be able to map your workflow onto SimpleCLI commands.

Comment: And in an external IDE?

Comment: Do you mean not all the KnowledgeFlow functions are into the Weka.jar file?

Comment: No, the weka.jar *IS* the Weka API. The KnowledgeFlow exposes a lot of it. But when writing your own Java code, you can do more than the KnowledgeFlow allows you to do.

Comment: Finally I solved manually . It was not quite difficult . I was new in java environement.